# How to disable automatic indentation in latex?

Tags: latex

I want to create a pdf in which there are short texts followed by images.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \section*{some title}
    A text... \\
    More text... \\
    \includegraphics{example.png}
    \newpage
    A text... \\
    More text... \\
    \includegraphics{example.png}
    \newpage
    A text... \\
    More text... \\
    \includegraphics{example.png}
    \newpage
    \section*{some title}
    A text... \\
    More text... \\
    \includegraphics{example.png}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that LaTex automatically indents "A text".
"More text" is not indented. If "A text" comes after \section*{} it is also not indented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can control the width of the indentation by changing `\parindent`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \section*{some title}
    A text... 
    
    More text...
    
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \newpage
    A text... 
    
    More text... 
    
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \newpage
    A text... 
    
    More text... 
    
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \newpage
    \section*{some title}
    A text... 
    
    More text... 
    
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(you shouldn't abuse `\\`  for line breaks, leave an empty line instead)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
I'm relativly new in latex and i though that \\ was meant for line breaks. I just read up on that. ;)

Comment: @Maxxx Easy rule of thumb:  only use `\\ ` in environments like tabulars etc.

Comment: Btw is there a way to reset the \parident option whithin the document if I want it to be different values at different parts of the doc?

Comment: @Maxxx Sure, you can use `\setlength{\parindent}{...}` wherever you like

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way is:

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```